# How to get raw json value from jsonToken using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I have json and I need to get raw json from one of its nodes, which contains all original characters including line breaks and spaces.
For example:

```
{
    "auth": {
        "hash": "f9d876df71dfc72810a497dc38d1c1f467c720d8171da5e2c974647978c645ae"
    },
    "request": {
        "p1": 1885,
        "p2": [
            "test"
        ],
        "p3": {
            "in": 10
        }
    }
}
```

I need to get value of request node as String with raw json like this:

```
{
        "p1": 1885,
        "p2": [
            "test"
        ],
        "p3": {
            "in": 10
        }
    }
```

I try:

```
    String rawRequest = null;

    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();
    JsonParser jsonParser = jsonFactory.createParser(json)
    JsonToken jsonToken = jsonParser.nextToken();
    while (jsonToken != null) {
        if (jsonToken == JsonToken.FIELD_NAME) {
            String fieldName = jsonParser.getCurrentName();
            if ("request".equals(fieldName)) {
                jsonParser.nextToken();
                rawRequest = jsonParser.getValueAsString();
                break;
            }
        }
        jsonToken = jsonParser.nextToken();
    }
```

but it`s not working.
How can I do that? In extreme cases, it is even possible to use third-party libraries.

Comment: I think your attempt is quite close. Instead of using .getValueAsString() you should extract the text from the beginning of the current token until you find the closing bracket for your object.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Paul Georg Podlech, as far as I understand, when extracting text, it looks for values in quotes, otherwise it returns null

Comment: Abhijit Sarkar, it returns value of token ("{" in this case)

Answer (score 1):

The solution I was able to do is as follows:

```
private String getRawRequest(String json) throws IOException {
    String rawRequest = null;
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();
    JsonParser jsonParser = jsonFactory.createParser(json);
    JsonToken jsonToken = jsonParser.nextToken();

    while (jsonToken != null) {
        if (jsonToken == JsonToken.FIELD_NAME) {
            String fieldName = jsonParser.getCurrentName();
            if ("request".equals(fieldName)) {
                jsonParser.nextToken();

                int startIndex = findCurrentTokenIndex(jsonParser, json);
                jsonParser.skipChildren();
                int endIndex = findCurrentTokenIndex(jsonParser, json);

                rawRequest = json.substring(startIndex - 1, endIndex + 1);
                break;
            }
        }
        jsonToken = jsonParser.nextToken();
    }

    return rawRequest;
}

private int findCurrentTokenIndex(JsonParser jsonParser, String json) throws IOException {
    JsonLocation startTokenLocation = jsonParser.getTokenLocation();
    int lineNr = startTokenLocation.getLineNr();
    int columnNr = startTokenLocation.getColumnNr();
    return findIndex(json, lineNr, columnNr);
}

private int findIndex(String json, Integer line, Integer position) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = json.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)));
    int index = 0;
    int currentLine = 0;
    while (true) {
        String lineData = bufferedReader.readLine();
        currentLine++;
        if (currentLine == line) {
            index += position;
            break;
        } else {
            index += lineData.length() + 1; //line break (without carriage return)
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

Looks rather inefficient, but I don't want to write my own parser. The weak point is the search for a position. In the case of adding a carriage return along with a line break.

Comment: You should try using getCharOffset or getByteOffset instead of reading the whole String a second time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jackson's `ObjectMapper` to read raw json and then extract request property like

```java
String rawJson = "" +
"{\n" +
"    \"auth\": {\n" +
"        \"hash\": \"f9d876df71dfc72810a497dc38d1c1f467c720d8171da5e2c974647978c645ae\"\n" +
"    },\n" +
"    \"request\": {\n" +
"        \"p1\": 1885,\n" +
"        \"p2\": [\n" +
"            \"test\"\n" +
"        ],\n" +
"        \"p3\": {\n" +
"            \"in\": 10\n" +
"        }\n" +
"    }\n" +
"}\n";

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = objectMapper.readTree(rawJson);
String rawRequest = node.get("request").toString();
System.out.println(rawRequest);
```

For this to work, you need `jackson-databind` and `jackson-annotations` dependencies.

Comment: Unfortunately, this removes all whitespace characters and newlines.

Comment: If you want you can reformat the json string returned by `node.get("request")`

Comment: json comes at runtime and I don't know what format it will have

Comment: json is used to calculate the hash so the format is critical